# FPS Demo Physi.js - Player sinking through floor

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, physijs

I am working on a FPS demo using three.js and physi.js (ammo physics) and I have a problem I can't solve. When I start the simulation and the player has not moved everything is good. When I move the player in any direction or jump, the player's mesh begins to fall through the floor (y-axis). The mesh is a `Physijs.CapsuleMesh` and the floor is a `Physijs.BoxMesh`. Can someone help me figure this out?

A url to the demo is below. The 2 important files are 'Player.js' and 'main.js'.

[FPS Simulation](http://snowcapdev.net76.net/)